# Search for file in a folder that is never the same

Tags: windows, powershell

What I have to do is the following:

In "c:\Program Files\" I have to search for  an .exe file and then gather the version of this file.

For now, I'm stuck with the .exe search. I did this for know but no output is shown:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Pr*\ -Filter SymCorpUI.exe -Recurse  | % {Write-Host $_.FullName}
```

I know how to gather the version:

```
[System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo("PATH OF THE FILE\ccc.exe").FileVersion
```

Maybe the result of the search should be put in a variable and then the content could be retreived in the getVersionInfo part but I'm totally stuck.

Any ideas / thoughts on how I can achieve this?

Many thanks in advance for your help :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're nearly there, you just need to store the output of `Get-ChildItem` into a variable. This will be an array of `FileInfo` objects, so you then need to iterate over them to pull the info you want, which will be the `fullname` property:

```
$f = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Pr*\ -Filter SymCorpUI.exe -Recurse
$f | % { [System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo($_.FullName).FileVersion
```

The `%` is shorthand for `Foreach-Object` and `$_` is the variable in the pipeline, which will be the `FileInfo` object. You then access the `FullName` property with `$_.FullName`. This will contain the full path of the file.

**Update:**

Seems the `-filter` functionality in powershell v1.0 is different to later versions and seems to only act on the path, not the filename so you'd need to do the following instead:

```
$f = gci "C:\Pro*" -recurse | ? { $_.name -eq 'SymCorpUI.exe' }
$f | % { [System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo($_.FullName).FileVersion
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer arco444 but I'm facing this error:

`Exception calling "GetVersionInfo" with "1" argument(s): "The path is not of a legal form."

Is -path C:\Pr*\ allowed to search for the exe in all folders names begining with Pr (Like Program Files)?

Thus, Iif I output the $f in a txt file, this one remains blank :/

Comment: Yes that should work. Are you sure any files were returned? What are the contents of `$f`?

Comment: When I do a "write-host $f", the variable seems to be empty. The output screen is empty.
In fact, I have to search for the file called "SymCorpUI.exe" that can be anywhere in a folder from C:\Program Files" and then get the file version of the .exe (which changes very often).

My script so far:

`1. $f = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Pr*\ -Filter SymCorpUI.exe -Recurse

  2. $f | % {[System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo($_.FullName).FileVersion}`

1. & 2. are for the lines in the editor ^^

Comment: That's why you get the error then. Are you sure the file actually exists, or that you have permission to read it if it does? Try replacing `SymCorpUI.exe` with `iexplore.exe` just to prove the script works.

Comment: I have full access to the file because without making the search, meaning 

[System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo("C:\Program Files\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint Protection\SymCorpUI.exe").FileVersion

I can have the file version. But with your script and iexplore.exe, this is the same thing: 

Exception calling "GetVersionInfo" with "1" argument(s): "The path is not of a legal form."

This is also working if I put the full path of the file to search, which is not the goal, but to search for it before :)

Thanks again :)

Comment: What version of powershell are you using?

Comment: Version is 1.0 and as I'm doing this for work, I cannot upgrade to a newer version and this script will be included into a big one used on lots of machine running PS 1.0

Comment: Don't know why but I did the following:

`$f = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Program Files\" -Filter SymCorpUI.exe -Recurse
$c = $f | % {[System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo($_.FullName).FileVersion}
write-host $c`

And now, this is working. Because the SymCorpUi.exe will only be in Program Files, I've wriiten a part of the path :D

In the meantime, many thanks for your inputs, your time and your help, much appreciated!

See you :)

Comment: Your updated answer works flawlessly :D A bit long because of the search but that's really good too.
Thanks again arco444